# iOS 3 - Click event on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

When I load my website on an old iPod Touch running iOS 3, my javascript (jQuery) doesn't work. I have a div that when clicked or tapped should toggle the display property of another div. It works on all other devices that I've tried it on, but all of them are newer. Here is what I'm working with:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mymenu").click(function(){
        $("#listNav").toggle(); 
        });
});
```

and

```
<a id="mymenu" class="clickable" onclick="" ><div class="clickable"><p>Menu &#9660;</p></div></a>
```

Some suggested creating a class that added `cursor: pointer`, which I have, but it doesn't help. I've also tried adding an empty `onclick=''` but that didn't help either.

I've also tried doing so with `.on("touchstart"...)` instead of `.click`, and even tried using a button instead of a div.

I wouldn't care for ensuring this backward compatibility but the problem is that this feature isn't working on the client's iPhone, so I HAVE to get it right.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 3.1.1 minified.

Comment: @maxshuty hey man, I just tried it with jQuery version 1.x and it worked! So thank you for that. Any idea why?

Comment: I added an answer for you :)

Comment: @maxshuty thanks, I just hit the little green check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/browser-support/) only supports iOS3 up to version 1.12, so after that things *could* break.

Rather than downgrading your jQuery verision I would highly recommend telling the client to upgrade their equipment to something more modern. If you must support it, then use an older version of jQuery.